# Match Day Month and Year To Data Source And return Sign In Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my data source
[image: Data Source]

This is my excel sheet
[image: Excel Sheet]

I want to match the following:

A5 on the excel sheet to the data source 'Staff_first_name' in column A

A2 on the excel sheet to the data source 'Year' in column B

B2 on the excel sheet to the data source 'Month' in column D

D4 on the excel sheet to the data source 'Day' in column E

Once all these have matched I want to display the 'Time In' from the data source within D5 but only display the earliest or the first time of that day (as there may be multiple records for each day)

Comment: Are you able to feed this into SQL? Asking since you tagged SQL

Comment: Hi Sorry, Didn't mean to tag SQL. No the data source is read from a ms access database.

Comment: pnuts, a pivottable is not an option (we need it in the format i specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out myself :) here is how it was done.

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Table_Entry_Sign.accde, MATCH(1, ([@Firstname]=Table_Entry_Sign.accde[Staff_first_name]) *(Table3[Year]=Table_Entry_Sign.accde[Year])*(Table3[Month]=Table_Entry_Sign.accde[Month])* (1=Table_Entry_Sign.accde[Day]),0), 3),[@[Start Time]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MIN(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$38=Sheet2!$A5)*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$38=Sheet2!$A$2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$38=Sheet2!$B$2)*(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$38=Sheet2!D$4),Sheet1!$C$2:$C$38,""))
```

where `Sheet1` is your data source (rows 2 to 38 in this example) and `Sheet2` is your summary worksheet...

It is using the multiplied equalities to do an array based `AND` and then returning the `MIN` time if they match... Only problem is that it might be really slow depending on the size of your data and number of employees (i.e. number of array formulas entered!)